# Calculation returning 0.0 in Java

Tags: java

This is a program for my Java class. My calculation for the weighted scores on the exams are 0.0. How do I stop it from calculating 0.0 and return the correct amount? I think it's an issue with double/int, but I don't know where the problem is. The method for the exams is at the bottom of my code.

Thanks

```
//This program calculates grades
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {
  public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static int assignmentScore = 0;
  public static int assignmentMax = 0;


  public static void main (String[] args) {
  giveIntro();

  System.out.print("Homework and Exam 1 weights? ");
  int homeworkWeight = console.nextInt();
  int exam1Weight = console.nextInt();
  int exam2Weight = 100 - homeworkWeight - exam1Weight;
  System.out.print("Using weights of " + homeworkWeight + " " + exam1Weight + " " + exam2Weight);

  System.out.println();   
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Homework:");


  System.out.print("Number of assignments? ");
  int numberOfAssignments = console.nextInt();
  assignments(numberOfAssignments);

  System.out.print("Sections attended? ");
  int sectionsAttended = console.nextInt();
  double weightedHomeworkScore = homework(sectionsAttended, homeworkWeight);

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Exam 1:");
  double weightedExam1Score = exam(exam1Weight);
  System.out.println();

  System.out.println("Exam 2:");
  double weightedExam2Score = exam(exam2Weight);
  System.out.println();

  double courseGrade = (double)weightedHomeworkScore + weightedExam1Score + weightedExam2Score;
  System.out.println("Course grade = " + round2(courseGrade));
  }

   //Returns the given double value rounded to the nearest hundredth.
   public static double round2(double number) {
      return Math.round(number * 100.0) / 100.0;
      }

   //Outputs introduction
   public static void giveIntro () {
      System.out.println("This program accepts your homework scores and");
      System.out.println("scores from two exams as input and computes");
      System.out.println("your grade in the course.");
      System.out.println();
      }

   //Returns the weighted score
   public static double weightedScore(double i, double j, double k) {
      return (i / j) * k;
   }

   //Takes the number of assignments input and asks for the score and max of each assignment
   public static void assignments(int number) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
         System.out.print("Assignment " + i + " score and max? ");
         assignmentScore = assignmentScore + console.nextInt();
         assignmentMax = assignmentMax + console.nextInt();
      }
   }

   //Takes the sections attended and homework weight, then returns the weighted homework score
   public static double homework(int i, int j) {
      int totalEarnedPoints = assignmentScore + (i * 4);
      int totalPoints = assignmentMax + 20;
      System.out.println("Total points = " + totalEarnedPoints + " / " + totalPoints);
      double weightedHomeworkScore = weightedScore(totalEarnedPoints, totalPoints, j);
      System.out.println("Weighted score = " + round2(weightedHomeworkScore));   
      return weightedHomeworkScore;
   }

   //Takes the exam weight, receives score and curve input, then returns the weighted scores for exams
   public static double exam(int examWeight) {
      double weightedExamScore = 0;
      System.out.print("Score? ");
      int examScore = console.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Curve? ");
      int examCurve = console.nextInt();
      int examCurvedPoints = Math.min(examScore + examCurve, 100);

      System.out.println("Total points = " + examCurvedPoints + " / 100");
      System.out.println("Weighted score = " + round2(weightedExamScore));
      return weightedExamScore = weightedScore(examCurvedPoints, 100, examWeight);
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it? are you sure all the values are what you think they are?

Comment: do you get any exceptions, have you run this through a debugger to see the results at each step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do this:

```
  double weightedExamScore = 0;
```

Then you do this:

```
  System.out.println("Weighted score = " + round2(weightedExamScore));
```

And then you do this:

```
  return weightedExamScore = weightedScore(examCurvedPoints, 100, examWeight);
```

There is nothing that modifies `weightedExamScore` between its initialisation with zero and the line where you print it out.

It will be zero.

Are you sure you don't want to calculate `weightedExamScore` *before* you print it out?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had moved the code because i needed to return it. I fixed it with this      `weightedExamScore = weightedScore(examCurvedPoints, 100, examWeight);
      System.out.println("Weighted score = " + round2(weightedExamScore));
           return weightedExamScore;`